# How can I intercept localhost traffic to/from WebGoat with ZED attack proxy?

Tags: proxy, webgoat, zap

For context I recently started working through the WebGoat appsec training program, and have hit a wall passing data to a program needed to complete a lesson.

One of the first lesson sets is entitled ""Access Control Flaws".

The first lesson description states:

> The 'guest' user has access to all the files in the lessonPlans/en directory. Try to break the access control mechanism and access a resource that is not in the listed directory. After selecting a file to view, WebGoat will report if access to the file was granted. An interesting file to try and obtain might be a file like WEB-INF/spring-security.xml. Remember that file paths will be different depending on how WebGoat is started.
>
> Current Directory is: /.extract/webapps/WebGoat/plugin_extracted/plugin/SqlNumericInjection/lessonPlans/en
>
> Choose the file to view: (List of files is below)

Choosing a file from the list gives an error that it is in the list. At first I tried manually typing out URLs, but realized I'd have to modify the request somehow. I caved and looked at the solution, which states:

> This lesson can be solved by intercepting the filename in WebScarab and replacing it with ../main.jsp which is a file located in a folder below the current directory.

Ok, so my instinct was correct - now comes operationalizing my intention into action.

Googling found that WebScarab == the old name for the OWASP Zed Attack Proxy.

More Googling found that in order to pass data to ZED, I needed to [set up a proxy in Firefox](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qZkxiRDRIAY).

So I went into Firefox, and set up the proxy. Note that 127.0.0.1 and localhost have been removed from the "No proxy for" field, :

[image]

However, when I navigate back into WebGoat (which is hosted locally at localhost:8080/WebGoat), nothing is intercepted. Traffic to external websites is *is* intercepted, so I suspect the issue is that for some reason ZAP is not receiving my WebGoat traffic.

I'm sorry this is a bit of a simple question, but I've researched a lot and can't seem to find any solutions.

TL;DR: How can I make sure ZED intercepts localhost traffic when viewing OWASP GOAT lessons in Firefox? (Traffic to external websites is intercepted, just not localhost traffic)

Answer (score 2):

1. Set the proxy host and port
2. Clear the 'No proxy for' field
3. In Firefox, in about:config, set network.proxy.allow_hijacking_localhost to true

Have you tried refreshing the relevant WebGoat page (Ctrl-Shift-R)?

I use ZAP to proxy to local applications all the time on Linux, Windows and Macs with no problem.

Btw ZAP is not the new name for WebScarab, its a completely different product ;) But WebScarab is no longer maintained while ZAP most definitely is :)

Answer (score 1):

localhost:8080/WebGoat and ZAP are working on the same Port (8080). Either change the port Number of ZAP or WebGoat.

I am making my WebGoat work on Port 80 and ZAP on Port 8080 which is the default